# Can Valgrind Reports be trusted if the tested program crashes

Tags: c++, crash, valgrind, memcheck

So I am running Valgrind memcheck on a program, but the program crashes when doing so. Probably because of some timing issues caused by Valgrind making the execution slower.

However I do get somekind of report telling me I am loosing memory at various places.
Can this be trusted when the program is crashing? I mean if the program crashes I can assume that there will be memory left unhandled. Can valgrind see this is the case and handle this memory differently?

I do get some reports of "Definitly lost" memory for example. Are they to be trusted?

Comment: I wouldn't trust it. Surely fixing the crash is more urgent than dealing with memory leakage anyway (assuming the two aren't directly related).

Comment: Probably more interesting than the leak report are the spots where valgrind reports illegal or uninitialized memory accesses (read/write) that may be a reason for your crash.

Comment: The crash is of course important, but since it is only crashing when running Valgrind it is not prioritized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'Definitely Lost' from valgrind (found during execution, by doing a leak search
or found at the end of the execution) is very probably a real leak.

But as suggested, fixing the crash is the first priority.